# Problem with BLTouch on Ender 3 Pro

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware, bltouch

I'm having some problems with my BLTouch.

[image]

Yesterday I got the 4.2.7 silent board delivered as well as the BLTouch and a glass bed. I was able to install the silent board without a problem and according to the many, many diagrams I've looked at, I also have my BLTouch installed correctly. I've installed several different firmware versions as well as manually compiling some.

*I used the following diagram which was provided in a link by the [seller](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZjVvaoADTIBsFHpvmfGUWR-nJY6VQirg). I also tried the firmware for Ender 3 pro 4.2.7 board on the Creality website as well as a few other firmware versions from various YouTube videos.*

[image]

When I start up my printer the BLTouch does its normal startup thing and my printer says it's ready. But when I try to auto home, bed level, or even manually control the BLTouch it doesn't extend at all. I've spent about 4 hours trying to figure it out on my own and I'm throwing in the towel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem in the future my solution was to loosen the screw on top of the touch just a little bit